# How to convert UTF-8 string to byte[] in u-sql custom Extractor?

Tags: c#, utf-8, azure-data-lake, data-extraction, u-sql

I am converting the string to byte[] using

> byte[] text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string_value);
>
> outputrow.Set(i, text);

But the output csv is not having the byte[] column. I think the column is not created for the records.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Extractors get info from files into rowsets, so I don't understand what do you mean by "output csv".